# why do I get this error: 'postcss' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file, when I use tailwindcss

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css, postcss, autoprefixer

[image]

```
PS C:\Users\Chidiebere\Desktop\bookmark reack landing page> npm start
```

> new@0.1.0 start
> npm run watch:css && react-scripts start

> new@0.1.0 watch:css
> postcss src/assets/tailwind.css -o src/assets/main.css --watch

'postcss' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
PS C:\Users\Chidiebere\Desktop\bookmark reack landing page> npm run build:css

> new@0.1.0 build:css
> postcss src/assets/tailwind.css -o src/assets/main.css

'postcss' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
PS C:\Users\Chidiebere\Desktop\bookmark reack landing page>

Answer (score 30):

Install `postcss` and `postcss-cli`

```
npm install postcss postcss-cli
```

Comment: Thank you! It has worked! I forgot to install the postcss-cli and that was why